# Oracle database new user to view all tables

Tags: oracle

I've created a new user, but I want to add some privileges to only allow the user to view or query some tables I've created with my admin user. I've seen that you can apply and create a VIEW, but will I have to create a VIEW for each table and apply it to my user or is there an easier way.

```
CREATE VIEW new_view AS SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;
GRANT ALL ON new_view to user;
```

Comment: It really depends on your goal. Are just looking to provide the user read only access, or hiding some information etc?

Comment: How about `grant select on TABLE_NAME to user`? If you just care about read only access to the table.

Comment: read only basically so they query the table

Comment: I would create a ROLE, grant to the role, and then add user to role.  You can then add additional users to the role as needed.  No need for a view if the example you show is really that simple.

Answer (score 0):

hi you only have to grant him the select any table system privilege

Select any table to *user*